# Can I script a function that lets me upload my own excel or csv file instead of using Google's drawcharts function?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, charts

As seen here, Google charts offers a powerful library: developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs

My issue is that I want to code a button and function that lets me upload an excel or csv file with the data in it, and for Google charts to create a chart out of my uploaded data. I do not want to use Google's existing "drawChart" function because I want to upload from a website page, not script in table data manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: By far the simplest approach is to download the files from your website to your computer and then upload them to your google account.  For that you need no special scripts.  Once they're on you google drive then you can write a script to display that data.  It is possible to get data directly from your website but you will have to know javascript httprequest and you will have to deal with authenticating your website so that it can access the google server neither of which are trivial issues.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the solution I'm asking for. And yes, I know how to script, code, etc.

Comment: Then I might guess you will want to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en)

Comment: I will look into that - thank you! My initial thought was to code a function within a function. As in, add a script into one of the existing functions... was just wondering if anyone else has already done this. I'll look into your suggestion as well, though - thanks again!

Comment: I recommend to post your suggestion as an answer so the community can have more visibility into this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some coding, it turns out I can upload a csv file to my web page, and I can then store that data as a variable. Inputting the variable into Google's existing arrayToDataTable component, I can then use it with charts.